# Replace on Array In Jquery without using loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a array on Jquery that have some values .Now i want to replace a character from all the items in the array if it have in the array.

```
var arrayData = [
       "Safi Landmark Hotel and Suites",
       "Safi Landmark Hotel Suites",
       "Safi Landmark Hotel and Suites"
];
```

This is my array now i want to replace 'and' from the items  with '&' .How can we do this without using loop.

Comment: Whatever mechanism you use, it will use an iterator inside to go through each item. Is this a matter of syntax?

Comment: That is our question also, how we can do this without using a loop !!!

Comment: I think you need to define what you mean by loop?

Comment: means for loop ..how we can do this with map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code with map for search and replace:

```
var testdata = $.map( [ 'a&b', 'abcz&mz', 'test' ], function( abc ) {
        return abc.replace('&',' and ');
    });
      alert(JSON.stringify(testdata));
  });
```

Comment: Works but the example replace `&` by `and` not the other way around like the original post so might be worth updating. It will also replace only the first instance of the searched string.

Comment: Also worth mentioning this will loop over the array and that `map` is slower than a normal `for`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xj52nyj0/1/

You can convert the array to string using `JSON.jsringify();`

and then replace like this.

```
var arrayData = [
       "Safi Landmark Hotel and Suites",
       "Safi Landmark Hotel Suites",
       "Safi Landmark Hotel and Suites"
];
var x=JSON.stringify(arrayData);
x = x.split('S').join("N");
```

This doesnt use any looping.

Answer (score 0):

No loop, no jQuery...

```
var arrayData = [
   "Safi Landmark Hotel and Suites",
   "Safi Landmark Hotel Suites",
   "Safi Landmark Hotel and Suites"
];

console.log(arrayData.join('|*|*|').replace(/and/g,'&').split('|*|*|'));
```

ps: '| * | * |' is just some unique delimeter..